# How best to Merge Git Changes over SSH

Tags: git, ssh, merging-data

I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way.

I have a software project with 3 developers all working on their own GIT Repo making frequent changes. They're pushing their changes to the server, where I then merge the changes and publish to the live web software.

I've been trying to find a solution that I can easily use to resolve conflicts when I merge code (there's typically a bunch of conflicts with each merger). My experience has been that VIM alone is terribly slow at this but I've found a program called Splice:
http://sjl.bitbucket.org/splice.vim/
That I'm trying to get the hang of it. However it seems that even this program tell you on the home page:

> "Splice is a merge tool which means you'll be working with it on your
>   development machine, not over SSH on your servers."

Is it such a big deal to do mergers on a production server over SSH? It seems like it's a much bigger pain in the butt to grab all that code that is on the server, download, merge, and re upload every time I have to merge code.

I'm new to this, but I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a better way to go about this?

All advice is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you are not supposed to run `git` commands on your server at all (apart from server-side setup of the barebone repo of course). You should do all your `git commit` on your development machine (which *may* however be a remote machine connected to via SSH, is that what you actually mean?) and then `git pull && git push` to update the server repo.

Comment: I actually do this sometimes. I have a development/test server running on a server, and while I try to make most changes on my local machine, sometimes in order to test integration with server resources I have to make the changes on the test server and run them there (I suppose I could deploy via git, test on server, go back to my local environment, make the changes, and redeploy, but that can be annoying and it also means I have to commit everything, including mistakes I correct immediately). In the rare cases where there a conflicts server-side, a tool would be nice.

Comment: @JordanReiter you could probably use some git hooks on the server to have certain commits trigger desired actions when pushed